# How to set time format on the time of binding?

Tags: asp.net, datetime, format

I want the time format should be like this `11.00 AM`. Please tell how can I? Thanks in advance. My code is:

```
<asp:DataList ID="dlEvents" runat="server" Width="100%">
 <ItemTemplate>
      <div class="date">
           <%#Eval("StartTime")%>          
            to
           <%#Eval("EndTime")%></div>
 </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

Comment: StartTime and EndTime is of `DateTime` data type?

Comment: can you update your quesiton by providing values which are displayed by default for Eval("StartTime") and Eval("EndTime")?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use,

```
<%#Eval("StartTime","{0:hh.mm tt}")%>
```

If type field type is *string* but it contains valid `datetime` value then use,

```
 <%# DateTime.Parse(Eval("StartTime").ToString()).ToString("hh:mm tt")%>
```

Comment: @RamSingh - This code will work for datetime fields. What is the datatype of "StartTime" and "EndTime"?

Answer (score 2):

```
<%# ((DateTime)Eval("StartTime")).ToString("HH.mm tt")%>
```

Comment: What is the type of StartTime in the Bind ?

Answer (score 0):

You can find here the format you want in a DATE or TIME..

http://www.geekzilla.co.uk/View00FF7904-B510-468C-A2C8-F859AA20581F.htm

```
<asp:DataList ID="dlEvents" runat="server" Width="100%">
 <ItemTemplate>
          StartTime = String.Format("{h:mm tt}", StartTime );
          EndTime= String.Format("{h:mm tt}", EndTime);
         <div class="date">
              <%#Eval("StartTime")%>          
               to
              <%#Eval("EndTime")%></div>
 </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will help you [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)